# InDesign - Can I set paragraph layering order (z-index) through styles?

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles

I know I can do this by using two separate text frames, but I'd like to know if I can adjust which lines of text show on top of others, via paragraph styles. I don't like having all sorts of text frames, if I can use just one.

I'd like my gold text to overlap the black text, from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Comment: Not possible use two text frames...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lines of text in InDesign will always be ordered like they are written. With the first line at the bottom and the following lines on top.

The only way to work around this using paragraph styles I know is a bit hacky:

**Write the first line last and move it up using *Baseline Shift*.**

[image]

This obviously only works if you always have the same number of lines before the line you shift upwards.

It can be annoying that the shifted paragraph leaves behind some empty space:

[image]

That can be avoided by setting the *Leading* of the shifted paragraph to *0*.

[image]

Now it instead is annoying when editing that you have two lines lying on top of each other.

Comment: Hacky, but works. Thanks. Can't believe I didn't think of this...

Comment: @Manly, you're welcome. You could of course also move the black text *downwards* instead if it somehow fits your layout better.

Comment: I received a bunch of book cover files recently where the title and subtitle had consistently been swapped by shifting the title up 30pt and the subtitle down 30pt so they switched places. No idea why the designer had done that, and it didn’t twig at first, so I spent a few frustrating moments trying to figure out what the hell was going on. Definitely an effective way of making a fellow designer want to murder you with a hatchet.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  Oh no, I hope this answer doesn't fuel that trend. Baseline shift tricks can be very confusion, but can also come in handy sometimes.